# UIWebView not opening the Installed Application but opens in safari

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiwebview

I'm using a UIWebview and I had loaded an URL which shows an alert to open the native Application that has been installed on my iPhone. On clicking the alert the application doesn't open in UIWebview but when I test the same URL in safari it works perfectly. Please let me know whether I have missed any steps.

And one more Update the above scenario works perfect in IOS 8.0 version but not in the above 8.0 versions. And i have tried with UIWebView and WKWebView

Thanks in advance.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let webV    = UIWebView()
    webV.frame  = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "someURL")! as URL) as URLRequest)
    webV.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(webV)

}
```

Comment: show your tried code always

Answer (score 0):

the simple way to load url in your webView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            webview.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://www.google.com")!))
        }
```

Comment: why you are not try with `webkit`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i had loaded the URL as same as above but after loading the URL, there was an popUp occurs in Webview to open the Native application by clicking on the alert there are no actions. But when i load the same URL in safari its works perfectly.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Whether the issue is in UIWebView or in the perspective URL loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the UIWebView is not forwarding the URL to the system so it can handle the launch of the other app.

If the requirements of your app allow to replace that webView with another view element, such a UIButton, I would encourage using UIApplication to open the URL when clicking the UIButton:

**Swift 3:**

```
  @IBAction func didClickButton(sender: Any){
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "<your_url>")!)
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Lujan Click event is handled in Webview